# Libgdx draws objects black instead of colored

Tags: libgdx

I have a starfield for a side scroller game. The stars are moving from right to left. There are three different types of stars fast, normal and slow simulating a parallax effect. Depending on their type they have different colors and speeds.

It works fine so far but the stars remain black.

The code of the starfield:

```
public class Starfield extends AbstractGameObject {

    public static final String TAG = Starfield.class.getName();
    private Array<Star> stars;

    public enum STAR_TYPE {
        FAST(255, 255, 255),
        NORMAL(190, 190, 190),
        SLOW(120, 120, 120);

        private int color;

        private STAR_TYPE(int r, int g, int b) {
            int R = r << 24;
            int G = g << 16;
            int B = b << 8;
            color = R | G | B | 0xff;
            //color = r << 24 | g << 16 | b << 8 | 0xff;
        }

        public static STAR_TYPE getRandomType() {
            return values()[MathUtils.random(0, values().length - 1)];
        }

        public int getColor() {
            return color;
        }
    }

    public Starfield() {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        stars = new Array<Star>();

        for(int i = 1; i <= Constants.COUNT_STARS; i++){
                stars.add(new Star());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        super.update(deltaTime);

        for(Star star : stars){
            star.update(deltaTime);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
        for (Star star : stars)
            star.render(batch);
    }

    public class Star extends AbstractGameObject {

        private STAR_TYPE starType;
        private Texture texStar;

        public Star() {
            init();
        }

        private void init() {
            Pixmap pixmap;

            position.set(MathUtils.random() * Constants.WORLD_WIDTH, MathUtils.random() * Constants.WORLD_HEIGHT);
            dimension.set(0.02f, 0.02f);

            starType = STAR_TYPE.getRandomType();

            pixmap = new Pixmap((int) dimension.x, (int) dimension.y, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
            pixmap.setColor(starType.getColor()); 
            pixmap.fill();
            texStar = new Texture(pixmap);

            switch (starType) {
                case FAST:
                    velocity.set(-0.5f, 0);
                    break;
                case NORMAL:
                    velocity.set(-0.2f, 0);
                    break;
                case SLOW:
                    velocity.set(-0.1f, 0);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void update(float deltaTime) {
            super.update(deltaTime);

            if(position.x <= 0)
                position.x = Constants.WORLD_WIDTH;
        }

        @Override
        public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
            batch.draw(texStar, position.x, position.y, dimension.x, dimension.y);
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering if the bit shift works properly but it does. Then I changed the color manually to something like `pixmap.setColor(1, 0, 0, 1);`. The Stars remained black. I debuged the render method and looked into texStar. The pixmap is saved correctly including the previously selected color (I can rule out the possibility that I override the color in other parts of my code). I suspected the draw method to be wrong and used `batch.draw(texStar, position.x, position.y);` instead. But then all stars disappeared for some reason. I don't understand why because the texture should have the dimension of the pixmap (0.02f). The overall render method renderWorld looks like this:

```
private void renderWorld (SpriteBatch batch) {
        worldController.camerHelper.applyTo(camera);
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(texBorder, 0, 0);
        worldController.starfield.render(batch);
        batch.end();
    }
```

Btw, the texBorder Texture consisting of couple of colored rectangles is drawn just fine. Any thoughts what the reason for this behaviour could be?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was this line:

```
pixmap = new Pixmap((int) dimension.x, (int) dimension.y, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
```

The dimension of a pixmap is an integer. `dimension.x` and `dimension.y` are way smaller than 1. So after casting they are 0. Changing dimensions to 1 makes the stars colorful.